# How to expand first div in accordion?

Tags: jquery

My current accordion container works.
https://jsfiddle.net/c9bwogte/

Im using a query to group the head and body, it works good.
How do I get it to expand the first head by default?
The first head would end up being the current year.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //toggle the component with class accordion_body
    $(".accordion_head").click(function () {
        if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
            $(".accordion_body").slideUp(200);
            $(".plusminus").text('+');
        }
        if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(200);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
        } else {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(200);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.click()` at the end to trigger the accordion:

```
$(".accordion_head").click(function () {
    if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
        $(".accordion_body").slideUp(200);
        $(".plusminus").text('+');
    }
    if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(200);
        $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
    } else {
        $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(200);
        $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
    }
}).click();
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eydyg8tb/)**

Comment: The code in your comment is different from the fiddle in your question. Let me take a closer look at this new code.

Comment: Put the click on the first accordion head instead: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hbgj1qwp/